# JQuery mutiple post in the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have three functions ,and every function post to special php page to get data..

and every function need some time because every php script need some time ..

```
function nb1() {
    $.post("p1.php", {
            action: 1
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, "json")
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log("error");
        });
}

function nb2() {
    $.post("n2.php", {
            action: 1
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, "json")
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log("error");
        });
}

function nb3() {
    $.post("c3.php", {
            action: 1
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, "json")
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log("error");
        });
}

$(window).load(function() {
    nb1();
    nb2();
    nb3();
});
```

how can i threading all posts to work in the same time ?

Comment: You need to remove all the `function` prefixes in your `load()` function.

Comment: sorry ,error in writing code ,remove prefixes ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery when function (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to wait for all three promises to resolve.

You only need to make sure you also return the promise in your nb1, nb2, nb3 functions.

```
  function nb1() {
        return $.post("p1.php", {
                action: 1
            }, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, "json")
            .fail(function(data) {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }

    function nb2() {
        return $.post("n2.php", {
                action: 1
            }, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, "json")
            .fail(function(data) {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }

    function nb3() {
        return $.post("c3.php", {
                action: 1
            }, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, "json")
            .fail(function(data) {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        $.when(nb1(), nb2(), nb3()).then(function(){
            ///
        });
    });
```

Do you really need to wait for window.load? Otherwise I would use document.ready beacuse it executes sooner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to call all ajax requests at once. And the `success` or `failure` events can be handled collectively.

Eg.

```
jQuery.when(

    jQuery.post("p1.php", {
        action: 1
    }),
    jQuery.post("n2.php", {
        action: 1
    }),
    jQuery.post("c3.php", {
        action: 1
    })

  ).done(function(a1, a2, a3){
    // handle success

    var p1_responseTxt = a1;
    var n2_responseTxt = a2;
    var c3_responseTxt = a3;

  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // handle error

});
```

Here, the `done` function's params `a1, a2, a3` correspond to the success data of `p1, n2, c3` respectively.